# How to extract the characters of a string and compare them with another string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I'm quite new to Python and could use some help:

I have a a string that a user puts in. I want to break down this string into characters so that I can compare each position to see if that position matches another string that is also broken down into characters.

What is the Pythonic way of doing so?

Here's an example so far:

```
theWord = "Mississippi"

guess = input('Enter your guess: ')

correctGuess = ""

for i in theWord[i]:
    if theWord[i] == guess:
        correctGuess = theWord[i]
    print(correctGuess)
```

Comment: You should clarify how you intend to compare individual characters in one string to the other string.

Comment: Can you provide an example of two such strings, and your desired output. Also what code have you tried so far, and where specifically you are stuck with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a string is a list of characters, accessible using an index inside square brackets. For example, the 2nd character in string1 can be accessed using `string1[1]`, the 3rd `string1[2]`.

You can also iterate through the characters directly using `in`.

```
for c in word:
     print(c)
```

Or you can iterate over the range and access the characters one at a time.

```
for c in range(len(string1)):
    if string1[c] == string2[c]:
        logic()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "World"
[char1==char2 for char1, char2 in zip(str1, str2)]
```

Output:

```
>>> [False, False, False, True, False]
```

By the way, you can iterate over a Python string like you would over an array since it has an iter method. And if you want to explicitely break down your string into characters, just call `list(yourstring)`:

```
list("Hello")
>>> ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming you're using Python 3.x. Since I don't know how Python 2.x works, you might have to double-check to see if the code works in your code as well if you're using Python 2.x.*

*Furthermore, the question is a little vague, so I'm answering to the best of my ability.*

If you want to check to see if `'ham'` is in `'eggshamspam'`, then you should use the line:

```
if 'ham' in 'eggshamspam':
    pass
```

To find the position of `'ham'` in `'eggshamspam'`, do:

```
'eggshamspam'.find('ham') #Returns index of 'ham'. If not found, returns -1.
```

You don't need to break it down into characters, but if you want to, the most pythonic way I can think of is:

```
myChars = []
for i in myStr:
    myChars.append(i)
```

Take a look at the string docs [online](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html), or type in `help(str)` in the command prompt (or IDLE) to look at the in-code docs. You can also do `dir(str)` to fetch a list of methods the `str` object has.

Good luck, and if I answered your question, a +1 would be great!